# Automate export of published Smartsheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to automate export of a published Smartsheet. I've seen various API examples, but all of them need {sheetId}. Unfortunately I just have the URL of the published sheet, and no access to the base sheet. 
Is there a way to do an export to excel programmatically on a published Smartsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the owner of the sheet?

In addition to the `sheet id`, you will need an access token that has permission to access the sheet in order to programmatically extract the data.

The only alternative would be scraping the data, which would be a painful endeavor.